# Using `jar` to create "zip" file ... Mac won't open the zip, says "It is an unsupported format" ... why?

Tags: windows, macos, jar, zip

I have a batch file that runs on a Windows 10 PC every night at 5am.  It generates a new 3-week trial license starting 'today', ZIPs up the product, and FTPs the zip file to the website.

Because there's no 'zip' command on Windows, I used JAR (from Java JDK) to "zip" it up like this:

```
jar cf c:\target\Application-1.5.zip -C Application-1.5/ .
```

It "zips" up everything in the `Application-1.5` directory into zip file `Application-1.5.zip`.

When I download the zip file on the Windows 10 machine it extracts correctly.

However, when I download the zip file on my MacBook (Catalina), the Mac won't unzip the file ... it says ... "Unable to expand "Application-1.5.zip".  It is an unsupported format.

UPDATE: When I use JAR on Mac to unzip it like this `jar -xf ./Application-1.5.zip` it works.  But that's not sufficient.

How do I make the zip file compatible with Mac's built in unzipper?

Comment: @Rob Thanks ... I just posted to askdifferent ... to extract on Mac I am doubling-clicking on the zip file, not typing a command.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407406

Comment: @Rob Just FYI, I thought to post it on stackoverflow because it's a problem related to my build system which I associated with programming issues.  But you're right, it's probably better suited to apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around my problem by installing 7-zip on Windows 10 and using that instead of `jar` like so ...

```
7z a c:\target\Application-1.5.zip .\Application-1.5\* -r
```

Mac likes the zip file produced by 7-zip, so this will work for me.

But I'd still like to know why Mac's build in Archive Utility rejects the zip file built with `jar`.